# ISNULL() function in SQL Server 2014 behaving unexpectedly

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Declare @Var1 Varchar(5) = Null
Declare @Var2 Varchar(10) = 'ABCDEFGHIJ'

SELECT ISNULL(@Var1, @Var2) AS Result
```

I excepted the result to be '`ABCDEFGHIJ'`, but the result is `'ABCDE'`.

Is this the normal behavior of the function or I am missing anything?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/5044/nulls/25800/coalesce#t=201703030715583559345

Answer (score 3):

You have used varchar(5) that's why this is happening

use below

```
 Declare @Var1 Varchar(50) = Null
```

this will give your expected answer

Answer (score 3):

You should use `coalesce` function because the `Coalesce()` function returns the first non-null value among its arguments.

```
SELECT COALESCE(@Var1, @Var2) AS Result
```

Or you can change size of your declared variable. Both will give you expected output.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, yes this is the normal behavior of `ISNULL`. it takes the type of the first expression.

reference here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

> The value of check_expression is returned if it is not NULL;
>   otherwise, replacement_value is returned after it is implicitly
>   converted to the type of check_expression, if the types are different.
>   replacement_value can be truncated if replacement_value is longer than
>   check_expression.

As an alternative you should rather use `COALESCE`

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>[COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)</kbd> Function : Not sure about why ISNULL returning output like this, but assuming that while checking `ISNULL(p1,p2)` it will consider size of first Parameter only.

```
SELECT COALESCE(@Var1, @Var2) AS Result
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because your source variable is of length 5 so it has truncated the other part

```
Declare @Var1 Varchar(10) = Null
Declare @Var2 Varchar(10) = 'ABCDEFGHIJ'

SELECT ISNULL(@Var1, @Var2) AS Result
```

Answer (score 0):

`ISNULL(@Var1, @Var2)` Statement will copies the value of `@Var2` to `@var1` if `@var1` is null, and Length of `@var1` is `5` ,thats why it is showing only  first five characters.